# Is capitalisation required for quoted speech after 'He said that...'

Tags: capitalization

I'm confused as to whether or not I need to start quoted speech when following 'He said that'. The sentence is, 'He said that 'Writing a novel is like heading out over the open sea in a small boat.' Does the W of Writing need caps?

Comment: You don't need caps or interior quotes: "He said that writing a novel is like ..." You can even do it this way: "He said writing a novel is like ..." Or you could write "He said, 'Writing a novel is like ...'"

Comment: Also check out https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/

Comment: If you're quoting a published text, or a famous author, I think you need quotes to show you're not paraphrasing.  Here you're quoting a novelist on writing.  This is a direct quote from John Gardner.

Comment: You can also say: He said that writing a novel is "like heading out over the open sea in a small boat."  I.e., you quote the unique part of what he said.

Comment: Or: To quote John Gardner, "Writing a novel . . ."

Answer (score 3):

Sorry but you missed the whole point.

If this is a direct quote then the capital is needed but the wording can’t include *that*. Rather it must be *He said(:) 'Writing a novel is…’*

If it’s an indirect quote then the capital would be wrong; the wording should include *that* and the text should run: *he said that writing a novel was…*

Comment: With some paragraph breaks and commas,  I might even upvote this.

Comment: Much thanks, Spencer. I haven't learned how to put paragraph breaks in Comments.

Comment: But you can put them in the ANSWER you posted...

Comment: Oh… so I did. I've edited that to include some breaks…

Comment: Thanks @RobbieGoodwin for this explanation. You people are so damn clever.